# for information retrieval course using python, accessing given tf-idf weight

Tags: python-2.7

I am doing this python program where i have to access :
This is what i am trying to achieve with my code: Return a dict mapping doc_id to length, computed as sqrt(sum(w_i**2)), where w_i is the tf-idf weight for each term in the document.
        E.g., in the sample index below, document 0 has two terms 'a' (with
        tf-idf weight 3) and 'b' (with tf-idf weight 4). It's length is
        therefore 5 = sqrt(9 + 16).

```
    >>> lengths = Index().compute_doc_lengths({'a': [[0, 3]], 'b': [[0,4]]})
    >>> lengths[0]
    5.0
```

The code i have is this:
        templist=[]
        for iter in index.values():
            templist.append(iter)
            d = defaultdict(list)
            for i,l in templist[1]:
                d[i].append(l)
                lent = defaultdict()
                for m in d:
                    lo= math.sqrt(sum(lent[m]**2))
    return lo

Comment: Can you please clarify your intent a bit? As it is, your data structure is a bit odd; You have a list of two elements contained inside another list that has no additional elements. Why not just have a single list? Is it possible that there would be multiple `[doc_id,value]` sets at each dictionary key? What is the operation you're trying to do across the set?

Comment: In other words, describe the problem itself, not just your implementation of a solution to the problem. Your implementation unfortunately isn't clear enough to serve as a description of the problem.

Comment: thats how i am being told to use by the professor. This is what i am trying to achieve with my code:
Return a dict mapping doc_id to length, computed as sqrt(sum(w_i**2)),
        where w_i is the tf-idf weight for each term in the document.

        E.g., in the sample index below, document 0 has two terms 'a' (with
        tf-idf weight 3) and 'b' (with tf-idf weight 4). It's length is
        therefore 5 = sqrt(9 + 16).

        >>> lengths = Index().compute_doc_lengths({'a': [[0, 3]], 'b': [[0, 4]]})
        >>> lengths[0]
        5.0

Comment: Ok, that helps. Please edit that comment into your original question with appropriate formatting so everyone can see it (and so it's easier to read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding you correctly, we have to transform the input dictionary:

```
ind = {'a':[ [1,3] ], 'b': [ [1,4 ] ] }
```

To the output dictionary:

```
{1:5}
```

Where the `5` is calculated as the euclidian distance for the value portion of the input dictionary (the vector `[3,4]` in this case), Correct?

Given that information, the answer becomes a bit more straight-forwards:

```
def calculate_length(ind):
    # Frist, let's transform the dictionary into a list of doc_id, tl_idf pairs; [[doc_id_1,tl_idf_1],...]
    data = [entry[0] for entry in ind.itervalues()] # use just ind.values() in python 3.X
    # Next, let's split that list into two, one for doc_id's, one for tl_idfs
    doc_ids, tl_idfs = zip(*data)
    # We can just assume that all the doc_id's are the same. you could check that here if you wanted
    doc_id = doc_ids[0]
    # Next, we calculate the length as per our formula
    length = sqrt(sum(tl_idfs**2 for tl_idfs in tl_idfs))
    # Finally, we return the output dictionary
    return {doc_id: length}
```

Example:

```
>> calculate_length({'a':[ [1,3] ], 'b': [ [1,4 ] ] })
{1:5.0}
```

There are a couple places in here where you could optimize this to remove the intermidary lists (this method can be two lines of operation and a return) but I'll leave that to you to find out since this is a homework assignment. I also hope you take the time to actually understand what this code does, rather than just copying it wholesale.

Also note that this answer makes the *very large asumption that all `doc_id` values are the same, and there will only ever be a single `doc_id`,`tl_idf` list at each key in the dictionary*! If that's not true, then your transform becomes more complicated. But you did not provide sample input nore textual explination indicating that's the case (though, based on the data structure, I'd think it quite likely).

## Update

In fact, it's really bothering me because I definitely think that's the case. Here is a version that solves the more complex case:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

def calculate_length(ind):
    # We want to transform this first into a dict of {doc_id:[tl_idf_a,...]}
    # First we transform it into a generator of ([doc_id,tl_idf],...)
    tf_gen  = chain.from_iterable(ind.itervalues())
    # which we then use to generate our transformed dictionary
    tf_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for doc_id, tl_idf in tf_gen:
        tf_dict[doc_id].append(tl_idf)
    # Now we proceed mostly as before, but we can just do it in one line
    return dict((doc_id, sqrt(sum(tl_idfs**2 for tl_idfs in tl_idfs))) for doc_id, tl_idfs in tf_dict.iteritems())
```

Example use:

```
>>> calculate_length({'a':[ [1,3] ], 'b': [ [1,4 ] ] })
{1: 5.0}
>>> calculate_length({'a':[ [1,3],[2,3] ], 'b': [ [1,4 ], [2,1] ] })
{1: 5.0, 2: 3.1622776601683795}
```

Comment: the output of just 5.0 is required, not {1:5.0} and your explanation does make sense. i will work based on that. thank you

Comment: @sjain Also if this solved your problem, please accept the answer (click the grey checkmark next to the answer) so that others know it solved the problem.